# Get the object of the whole quotation in observer

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, quote, bundled-product

I am doing this:

```
public function setQuoteShippingMethod (Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

       //to have more code
    }
```

but it takes the last item (product) in the quotation (i.e. I have 4 items). I want to take the object of the whole quotation (bundle product), so I manipulate its shipping method.

I am observing `checkout_cart_product_add_after`. The point is - I have a quotation in the Customer Account's quotes - and when you open(view) the quotation - you can click "Add to cart". That's where my method is caught.

Comment: What event are you observing?

Comment: @Marius - updated. :)

Comment: try with `$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem(); $quote = $item->getQuote()`...if I understood correctly the question

Comment: Ah, I see. I tried also with `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()` and didn't work, so I was wondering what's wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments it seams that this solves the problem:

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$quote = $item->getQuote()
//do stuff with $quote
```